# Fatou's Lemma Counterexample

Tags: measure-theory

Give an example of sequence of Measurable functions defined on some measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$  such that $f_{n} \to f$ pointwise almost everywhere on $E$ but $$\int\limits_{E} f \ dm \not\leq \lim_{n} \inf \int\limits_{E} f_{n} \ dm$$

Comment: I know that this is very much related to Fatou's lemma but i am unable to find an example.

Comment: How is it related to fatou's lemma? What is fatou's lemma? What have you tried? Why do you care? Including such things in your question makes it a pleasure to read (bolstering the site and your reputation) and to answer (since answering, knowing your answer will be useful, makes it all the more worthwhile)...

Comment: @Tom Boardman: Doesn't fatou's lemma deal with this type of integral. The final statement of Fatou's lemma is $$\int\limts_{E} f \ dm \leq \lim_{n} \inf \int\limits_{E} f_{n} \ dm$$

Also, whats wrong in thinking that way. Its my think. I did think something about characteristic function, but didn't work.

Comment: @Chandru1: Maybe you could edit your question and exchange \nleq with \not\leq so that the indented becomes more readable. (As a bounty you'll get an upvote from me.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Fatou’s Lemma *holds* for non-negative measurable functions, I suppose you are looking for an example involving not necessarily non-negative functions.

Take, for instance, $f_n(x)=-1_{n\leq x\leq n+1}$ (just $-1$ times the indicator function on the interval $[n,n+1]$). Then $f=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\inf f_n=0$. Hence,
$$
0=\int f dm \not\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf\int f_n dm = -1.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I understood your solution nicely.

Comment: I was answering the OP's question as it could be read, and in a similarly bald fashion to the way in which the question was asked. Since he had not bothered to fix the Tex or explain the background I read his \nleq as \neq. My attempt to make a point following my initial comment went, it seems, unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

For $E=[0,1]$ set: $f_n(x)=n- n^2x$ for $x\in [0,\frac1n]$ $f_n(x)=0$ else.

Comment: n*exp(-nx) will also do the job.

Comment: Also, use the open interval if you want a defined pointwise limit.

Comment: I think that this is an example for strict inequality in Fatou's Lemma. It is not a counterexample to Fatou's Lemma (which cannot get along with non-negative measurable functions, because these obey Fatou's Lemma).